# How to pass a state from component to a parent - the App.js (click outside to close navbar)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to pass a state from component `Navbar.js` to the `App.js` to do when I click outside the `SideMenu()` in closes the navbar. I passed the State props from parent to a child `Navbar.js` and it doesn't close when I click outside Navbar

-Defined `const [isSideMenuOpen, setIsSideMenuOpen] = useState(false);` in App.js

-Added props to pass to a child component   `<Navbar setIsSideMenuOpen={setIsSideMenuOpen} isSideMenuOpen={isSideMenuOpen} />`

-Destructuring `setIsSideMenuOpen` and `isSideMenuOpen` in Navbar.js (check the code below)

App.js

```js
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Navbar from "../comps/Navbar";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

let useClickOutside = (handler) => {
  let domNode = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    let maybeHandler = (event) => {
      if (!domNode.current?.contains(event.target)) {
        handler();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", maybeHandler);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", maybeHandler);
    };
  });

  return domNode;
};

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [isSideMenuOpen, setIsSideMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  let domNode = useClickOutside(() => {
    setIsSideMenuOpen(false);
  });
  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <Navbar
        setIsSideMenuOpen={setIsSideMenuOpen}
        isSideMenuOpen={isSideMenuOpen}
        domNode={domNode} // NEWLINE! passing to the SideMenu() function
      />
      <div ref={domNode}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

../components/Navbar.js

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { HiMenuAlt1, HiOutlineX } from "react-icons/hi";

export default function Navbar({ isSideMenuOpen, setIsSideMenuOpen }) {
  const showSideMenu = () => {
    isSideMenuOpen ? setIsSideMenuOpen(false) : setIsSideMenuOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="absolute z-40 w-full h-8  text-cyan-600 flex flex-row justify-between items-center text-2xl ">
      <div className="brand-logo text-xl font-bold px-2 font-extrabold text-cyan-600">
        Trener
      </div>
      <ul className="md:flex hidden menu-list text-xl font-bold ">
        <li className="menu-list-item px-2">
          <a href="/">Strona główna</a>
        </li>
        <li className="menu-list-item px-2">
          <a href="#b">O mnie</a>
        </li>
        <li className="menu-list-item px-2">
          <a href="#c">Plany treningowe</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          showSideMenu();
        }}
        className="lg:hidden menu-button"
      >
        {isSideMenuOpen ? (
          <HiOutlineX className="w-8 h-8 px-2 bg-red-600" />
        ) : (
          <HiMenuAlt1 className="w-8 h-8 px-2" />
        )}
      </button>
      {isSideMenuOpen ? SideMenu() : ""}
    </div>
  );
}

// NEW LINE - Destructuring props domNode
function SideMenu({domNode}) {
  return (
    <div className="fixed z-20  w-1/2 sm:w-1/4 lg:hidden bg-gray-300 top-8 right-0 p-3" ref={domNode}>
//NEW LINE - assign ref={domNode}
      {/* sagsa */}
      <ul className="menu-list flex flex-col text-lg font-bold">
        <li className="menu-list-item py-2 hover:bg-white hover:text-blue-700">
          <a href="/">Strona główna</a>
        </li>
        <li className="menu-list-item py-2 hover:bg-white hover:text-blue-700">
          <a href="/about">O mnie</a>
        </li>
        <li className="menu-list-item py-2 hover:bg-white hover:text-blue-700">
          <a href="#c">Plany treningowe</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

UPDATE:
I added `domNode={domNode}` // NEWLINE! passing a prop to the `Navbar.js` -> `SideMenu()` function

```js
// NEW LINE - Destructuring props domNode
function SideMenu({domNode}) {
  return (
    <div className="fixed z-20  w-1/2 sm:w-1/4 lg:hidden bg-gray-300 top-8 right-0 p-3" ref={domNode}>
//NEW LINE - assign ref={domNode} 
// (...)
```

Occured an error:
`Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'domNode')` in `function SideMenu({ domNode }) {`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've defined **setIsSideMenuOpen** in child component which is Navbar.js

What you can do define

```
const [isSideMenuOpen, setIsSideMenuOpen] = useState(false)
```

in the App.js and then pass it as props to Navbar. That way you can handle the isSideMenuOpen from both the parent and child

Comment: Hello, I passed the props to a child, but the navbar doesn't close when I click outside. I updated the code. When I click on the button it closes and opens so something may be wrong with the eventListener... idk

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the state and it's setter Function form child component to parent component,
There are following approches you can do

1. Define the state, and its Setter function in App.js and then pass both state and it's setter as a props to Navbar.js and then use them here as a props.
2. Use **State Lift up** concept Make a combine parent component and and define

   const [isSideMenuOpen, setIsSideMenuOpen] = useState(false);

here and pass this as a props to both component's App.js and Navbar.js.

3. You can simple use redux to avoid state passing issue.

Comment: Hello, I passed the props to a child, but the navbar doesn't close when I click outside. I updated the code. When I click on the button it closes and opens so something may be wrong with the eventListener... idk

Comment: For this  you have to add On-click to parent div of both component because you want to close when it is clicked any where outside

Comment: isn't `let domNode = useClickOutside(() => { setIsSideMenuOpen(false); });` handles this?

Comment: I dont get it, would you please give me an example?

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWO1b6EoCnQ&t

Comment: When I pass `domNode={domNode}` to `Navbar` component and assign the `ref={domNode}` to `SideMenu` function in `Navbar` there is an error: ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'domNode')```  ---> `function SideMenu({ domNode })`